# Eclipse Tomcat apr

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, apr

I use Tomcat 6.0.32 as standalone - APR load without problems.
But when install the same in Eclipse and run - apr not found.
What can be the reason?
Thanks.

Comment: You may need to configure APR in eclipse as well. it depends on how you've setup tomcat server in eclipse. Why do you need it in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a VM argument in Run configuration for Tomcat server in eclipse.

```
-Djava.library.path="D:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with Tal. The shared library must be found by the tomcat process. On Linux, you can use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable for this.

Servers -> Click on you tomcat -> Overview -> Click on 'Open launch configuration'
-> Tab 'Enviroment -> New...

BTW, if you want to use the tomcat NIO connector, you have to edit 'conf/server.xml' in the 'server path'. If you use 'Use workspace metadata' (Overview), your changes will get overridden from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Because Eclipse change configuration of Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

you must put the foldre in which the tcnative dll resides in the path and restart eclipse.
usually it's in tomcat's bin folder.

see link : http://snipplr.com/view/50950/