# Configure APR connector in Spring Tool Suite/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, apr

I want to configure APR connector in Spring Tool Suite's tomcat in linux(CentOS7).

Using apr 1.5.2, tomcat-native 1.1.33, Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2, tomcat 7.0.57.

Followed this [tutorial](http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204) and installed apr and tomcat-native libraries. Then based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926382/eclipse-tomcat-apr), configured the jdk path to eclipse tomcat's configuration arguments. Now when i start the server, i get

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:972)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.. Need to set the envioronment variable of tomcat

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH - /usr/local/apr/lib
```

See the second answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926382/eclipse-tomcat-apr)